# How can I change this code correctly?

Tags: c#, sql

I Made a datagrid with a button. When I click the button it should load data from the database into the grid.

This works. I linked foreign keys to this datatable, and they also load in the datagrid, but they get displayed as dbname.tablename. I want this to display as their name.

How can I do this?

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
reservering deResv = new reservering();
chalet hetHuis = new chalet();
klant deKlant = new klant();

public testpanel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var listResv = db.reserverings.OrderBy(x => x.KlantId).ToList(); // 
    dgTest.ItemsSource = listResv;
}
```

Let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: It sounds like the DataGrid's default binding action is to simply show a string representation of each property, and for properties of reference types that would just be the class name.  One option could be to flatten the objects into custom DTOs of simple properties (even just an anonymous object in-line, if this is the only place you need it).  Another option might be to add `.ToString()` implementations to those types, though that seems a bit drastic for this.

Comment: The simplest way is to add a callback to datagridview's DataBindingComplete and then use that as the place for handling custom formats and names.